# Is the autofocus mode triggered by default in AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I'm working on an iOS camera app and I have a question about autofocus. I implemented a camera autofocus function, which detects where a user tapped on the screen and set the camera focus to that point. It works fine for now, however, the app seems to set focus to whatever on the center of the screen when running the app and before the user starts tapping the screen. For example, after running and building the app, if I place an object, which locates really close to me, at the center of my camera app, the camera clearly focuses on the object. Then if I take another object which locates sort of far and places the object at the center of the screen, the camera app focuses on the object. Those happen before the user taps anywhere on the screen. So, I was wondering if the AVFoundation camera autofocuses whatever on the center of the screen by default. I read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1389191-focusmode) but it doesn't have a clear explanation so just wanted to make sure.